# Typical log4j layout

Tags: java, log4j

I'm wondering if there's a typical log4j typical ConversionPattern layout that can be used with log4j. The objective is to set up a usable log4j quickly.

I've choose this parameters ; is there some others which can be useful ?

Console appender

```
%d %p [%t] %c{2} (%F:%L) %x - %m%n
Date Priority [OutputName] Category (File:Line) DiagnosticContext - SuppliedMessage/n
```

File Appender

```
%d %p %c{2} - %m%n
Date Priority Category - SuppliedMessage/n
```

Here's the log4j Pattern parameters
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Comment: Depends on what you want to use the logging for. Using the Diagnostic Context for example is slow, so I wouldn't want it in a productive system.

Comment: I agree. Just looking for a "standard" pattern, when initialize a projet, with the most important parameters. If by any chance, this pattern is used in production context, you can still use it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern layout exists to be flexible, to let everyone tune it to match his/her needs, so whatever you feel appropriate for you would do well, with one note: make sure you understand performance implications of what you come up with (note all "WARNING: Generating caller location information ..." on https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html). [This](http://bobah.net/d4d/source-code/misc/log4j-configuration-and-usage) is my typical usage.

Answer (score 0):

I usually set up 2 appenders

- one console, filtered on info level, supposed to be looked in real time, to know "what is happening now", with level + category + message, **no** date, **no** file / line
- one file, for analysis / debugging, with additionnal informations  : date (iso format, easy to sort), thread (very important in multithreaded context), file and line (supposed to be costly, but it's usually not an issue), sometimes custom properties from MDC